# Hide Blog Post Author on Wordpress Theme (The Fox)

Tags: css, themes, blogs, author

On the post archive page [here](http://staceyrosscohen.com/news-and-insights/)

And individual post pages, like [this](http://staceyrosscohen.com/outdoor-voices-ceo-tyler-haney-makes-noise-in-the-activewear-industry/)

I'd like to hide the author, which currently says "by coadmin", but no plug-ins i've tried work, and I can't find any CSS lines referring to the author specifically. I can hide all the info by targeting .post-info {display: none} but I only want the author hidden.

If I target the specific div of the author name I can hide it, like:

```
#rd_tebhz4xe9fvnw90a41ec > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.post-info > a:nth-child(1) {
display: none;}
```

But that leaves "by" still there.

Does anyone have any suggestions? The Wordpress theme is called "The Fox".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following CSS:

This hides the author.

```
.post .post-info a[rel="author"] {
    display: none;
}
```

This shifts the remaining text to the left and hides the "By | ".

```
.post .post-info {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -3em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to alter the php file to just not have it render. 
However, if you absolutely must use only css, the following is quite hacky, but should do the trick:

```
.post-info{
  margin-left: -40px !important;
}
.post-info a[rel="author"]{
  display: none !important;
}
```

[image]